# Difference between Argcis v10.2.8 and Argcis v100 (Android)

Tags: android, arcgis, arcgis-android-api

I'm new to arcgis.
I'm trying to develop an android app based on argcis. When i use v10.2.8 as used in guide (https://developers.arcgis.com/android/10-2/guide/welcome-to-the-help-for-arcgis-runtime-sdk-for-android.htm), there is no problem. Also, Apk size is small. But when i look samples in github page of esri (https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-samples-android), they used v100. When i use v100, apk size raised (~60 mb) and samples didn't work.
I didn't understand which version should be used and what are differences between them.

I'm totally confused. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's in the documentation itself https://developers.arcgis.com/arcgis-runtime/choosing-the-right-version/ ..I never used this api so I don't know anything else.

Comment: v100 is awfull. They removed alsmost all one-string usefull tools. Now to do some clasterization you should write own code. Measurement tool was also removed, navigation widget thrown away. V100 has many bugs: for example currently all vector map text lables is placed over your program graphic, vector map rendered badly and map needs workarounds to be rendered good...